# I want to enable or disable a "blog post" by dropdown from admin panel

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to enable or disable post by clicking drop down values. How can i do that?

```
<script>
  function disable(post)
  {
      if(post=="0")
           document.getElementById("status").disabled=true;
      else
          document.getElementById("status").disabled=false;
  }
</script>

<select name="status" id=<?= $row["id_post"] ?>  onChange="disable(this.value)">
  <option value="0">Status</option>
  <option name="enable"  id="enable"  value="1">Enable</option>
  <option name="disable" id="disable" value="0">Disable</option>
</select>
```

i have a field in my database 
table name "r_post"   column name "status int(1)"

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "disable a blog post"? Currently, your JavaScript will disabled the `select` element when the "Disable" `option` is selected - what is the desired behaviour?

Comment: i mean it is my admin panel.   in front end there are posts so i want to handle front end posts from admin for that i want to add enable disable post.  When i click enable in my admin  dropdown post the post should be disable on frontend..Default behaviour should be disable.

Comment: your question is not clear. For now if you want to select same selec box on selecting disable option then change the id of select box it should be "status" not "staus"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use JavaScript for Enable and Disable as per your code.

```
<select name="status">
  <option>Status</option>
  <option value="1" <?php ($row["status"]==1)?'selected':'' ?>>Enable</option>
  <option value="0" <?php ($row["status"]==0)?'selected':'' ?>>Disable</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit Your Code
Firstly you need to create a php action page, if you want to create this page, then you can write down the code into you same php file. then on select for select box you need to submit the form. Then action will be goes on same page and your update query will update your blog record.
Your need to add your table id the in hidden input type so the query will get the exact address.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <?php
      if(isset($_POST['status']))
      {
        $sql=mysql_query("update blog set status='".$_POST['Status']."' where id='".$_POST['id']."'");
        echo ("blog updated successfully");
      }
    ?>
    <title>Your Page name</title>
    </head>
    <body>

<form name="myform" action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
<select name="status" id="status1" onchange="this.form.submit()">
  <option value="0">Status</option>
  <option name="enable"  id="1enable"  value="1">Enable</option>
  <option name="disable" id="1disable" value="0">Disable</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: currently i have not connected to any data base for this drop down is it necessary to save enable and disable data.? if yes can please provide the form code i am new to php. thank you

Comment: what platform you are using? i mean are you using a mvc or core ?

Comment: core php is my platform